# magento google analytics order data is showing double

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

We have installed yireo google tag manager for GTM.

Issue is when I order google analytics is showing 2 transactions, 2 qty and 2 unique purchases and also revenue

[image]

can anyone help me on this issue

thanks